# Change body opacity keyframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyframe

I want to change the body opacity using keyframes, also open to use javascript as my end goal is getting a bunch of pictures and making them into a slideshow type thing in the background, ***not using a div*** as that messes up the other content I have on the website,however, obviously if the only way is using a div then I guess I'll have to :)

Th color changing works but not the opacity.

Was wondering if someone could help, here is my css.

```css
body {
  animation: back 5s infinite;
  
}

@keyframes back {
  0% {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    background: yellow;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me ‍♂️

Comment: @D.Pardal only the color change is working fine, not the opacity change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of [the background propagation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-css-backgrounds-3-20171017/#special-backgrounds) making the background on the html element and no more the body element.

To avoid this add a white background to html (or any non transparent background) and make sure the body is at least full height:

```css
body {
  animation: back 5s infinite;
  margin:0;
  min-height:100vh;

}

@keyframes back {
  0% {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    background: yellow;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

html {
  background:#fff;
}
```